# Как вы делить всю область которую видит камера, любым цветом?(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

Хочу определять какие терейны подгружать, относительно того куда смотрит камера и для начало ищу простой способ выделить область на терейне которую видит камера. Возможно это сделать? И как если да ?

Comment: Ну вы можете закрасить урезанную пирамиду видимости, но что вам это даст? :) Я уже говорил в другом вашем вопросе, QuadTree вам в помощь.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я прочитал пока про QuadTree, но не углублялся пока, НО буду дальше изучать . Выделение области которую видит камера мне даст возможность определить вышел за пределы  террейна обзор беспилотника, а потом это поможет создать ограничение либо, подгрузку террейнов. И вообще есть идея еще имитации работы локатора . Ответ мне в любом случае пригодиться

Comment: Деревья квадрантов довольно часто используют для определения коллизий объектов. Если представить, что части карты - это квадраты, а взгляд камеры - это, по факту, усеченная пирамида, которую можно приблизить к кубу, то получается решение вашей задачи ;)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  Если не сложно, можно более подробно описать способ решения этой задачи? Я пока отдаленно представляю как это можно сделать и у меня есть белый пятна в этом вопросе

Comment: Тут подробнее - это уже конкретная реализация, чем мне заниматься лень, если честно :P

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  Вы и так заслужили денежный донат. Если договориться по деньгам . Сможете написать пример? до ответа 50 % , 50% после.  На меня свалилось просто куча задач, после уходы сотрудницы и просто не хватает времени чтоб успеть всё сделать.